# ssh port forwarding does not work. Getting error

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd, port-forwarding

I have a local laptop MacOS hence called `localmac` having `macuser` that needs to be controlled (by firing ssh commands) by a remote server hence called `remotelinux` having `linuxuser`.

On my `localmac` i m able to successfully `ssh linuxuser@remotelinux`

On my `localmac` I did post tunneling using the below command:

```
ssh -fnN -R 4444:localhost:22  linuxuser@remotelinux
```

Now, on my `remotelinux` i try to copy the keys using the below but I get the error:

```
$ ssh-copy-id -p 4444 macuser@localhost
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: Source of key(s) to be installed: "/home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: INFO: attempting to log in with the new key(s), to filter out any that are already installed
/usr/bin/ssh-copy-id: ERROR: ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I understand the above failed, however I try to fire the hostname command on remotelinux like below:

```
[linuxuser@remotelinux ~]$ ssh -p 3334 macuser@localhost 'hostname' -vvvv
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
[linuxuser@remotelinux ~]$ ssh -p 3334 macuser@localhost -vvvv
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "localhost" port 3334
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 3334.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/linuxuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

On the `localmac` i found the below message printed for each ssh command i fired from `remotelinux`

```
SSH tunneling: connect_to localhost port 22: failed
```

Can you please suggest How can I get this to work?

Comment: Could it be that `sshd` is not listening at port 22 on `localmac`? Confirm this by running `ss -nltp | grep 22` or `ss -lntp | grep ssh` as root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remote login is disabled by default on a MacOS laptop, hence SSH fails. Go to preferences and enable it.

Comment: Correct answer @Bruce Malaudzi Thank you!